# IOS Simulator: Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7.1

When I run an iOS application in the iOS 9.0 simulator I am getting the following warning message.

> > Warning message : "Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100"

Has anyone seen this error before?  Have you been able to solve it?  What did you do to fix it?

Comment: and the question is how to fix the warning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can ignore this error if you want to; it's nothing to do with your code, it's just Apple's logging code pointing out that you have enabled a particular setting.

If you desperately want it gone, open the Simulator on your Mac, go to the Debug menu, then choose Graphics Quality Override > Device Default. You probably have it set to High Quality right now, which is what the warning message is telling you about.

Comment: you can also reset all content and settings of the simulator (menu option: "Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings..." -> "Reset"), note: this will delete all the installed apps and any settings you set to your simulators (iPhone, iPad, apple tv....)

Comment: @TwoStraws answer does fix the error message, but now I am curious how to get the High Quality image in there in the first place. Do I need to put a "universal" size PDF in there or do all 1, 2 and 3x, or either?

Answer (score 4):

above answer is good. but if you need a graphic answer, please see below picture

[image]