# How to get current location in ios in simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, currentlocation

i am using this code to get current location but not getting the correct result to get the current location in simulator,

```
-(void)initLocationManager
{
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    if (([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]))
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    //[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    // [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    //   NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    // NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    latitud = location.coordinate.latitude;
    longitud = location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",latitud,longitud);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

please tell me how to get this current location, i am getting tired trying this from the morning. please help me

Comment: location updates are intended to work on real device. You would not be able to get current location in simulator .

Comment: you cannot get your current location using simulator,use device.

Comment: i am setting the location from debug>location>custom location , but still not getting the location which i am setting there

Comment: hey @user6438311 have you fix this ?

Comment: no i am not getting the response what i want , i am not getting the current location latitude and longitude therefore i will test i device so that may be on device it shows corrrectly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a GPX file by using following steps:

- Go in project--> Add new --> iOS -- > Resource and select GPX file

[image]

- Now you need to do small code in to GPX file as following:

---

```
<!--
        Provide one or more waypoints containing a latitude/longitude pair. If you provide one
        waypoint, Xcode will simulate that specific location. If you provide multiple waypoints,
        Xcode will simulate a route visitng each waypoint.
 -->
<wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030237">  // here change lat long to your lat long
     <name>Cupertino</name> // here set name 

     <!--   
            Optionally provide a time element for each waypoint. Xcode will interpolate movement
            at a rate of speed based on the time elapsed between each waypoint. If you do not provide
            a time element, then Xcode will use a fixed rate of speed.

            Waypoints must be sorted by time in ascending order.
      -->
     <time>2014-09-24T14:55:37Z</time>
</wpt>
```

- Now go to edit schema

  [image]
- And select `run` and do in `Option` menu select like following there is appear our GPX file select that and run and close:

[image]

That's it now you can get location of your added lat long in GPX file.

**UPDATE**

Following is a code for enable location:

- In info.plist you need set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` about location services.

[image: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription]

**Now your .h class**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *lblLat;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *lblLong;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

**.M class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];


    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        lblLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        lblLong.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

Working demo code: https://github.com/nitingohel/UserCurrentLocation_Objc

Comment: there must be some code for to find current location in the device and save that latitiude and longitude in some string , if yes then please share

Comment: but i am not getting the current location from the above code i have done every thing, i am getting zero

Comment: i just create an example code and attached demo as well check you are missing set enable location services

Comment: 2016-06-24 17:23:58.880 UserCurrentLocation_Objc[4617:171406] didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
2016-06-24 17:23:58.972 UserCurrentLocation_Objc[4617:171406] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
 this error is coming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263626/ios-simulator-simulator-user-has-requested-new-graphics-quality-100

Comment: Thank you very much  @Nitin Gohel

Answer (score 5):

In simulator you need choose location simulation in Debug Area

[image]

or in Edit Scheme

[image]

or you can add your own GPX file with coordinates

Comment: there must be some code for to find current location in the device and save that latitiude and longitude in some string , if yes then please share

Comment: Did you entered to delegate method `didUpdateLocations` after `startUpdatingLocation` If not try to add property to your class and set it `self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`

Comment: This is work perfectly for simulator. Any other solution to custom current location with move and search. I am successfully down this with google integration pods. but when i am customized. It dose' work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get current location directly in simulator, you have to go to location in `Debug>location>custom` of simulator and set latitude and longitude.

Comment: i am setting the location from debug>location>custom location , but still not getting the location which i am setting there

Comment: try this, select none first in location and then again click on custom location and set the lat and long

Comment: there must be some code for to find current location in the device and save that latitiude and longitude in some string , if yes then please share